# Navigation Bar's Title View Overlaps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I have added a custom titleView in Navigation Bar.

In every screen change I am adding another title View.

The problem is that the previous one is not get removed and I can See all Views at a time.

Here is my code:

```
    UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblTitle.text = text;
CGSize lblSize = [Utility sizeOfText:text withFont:kCGFontMedium(19)];
lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(60, 9, lblSize.width, lblSize.height);
lblTitle.font =kCGFontMedium(19);
lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[lblTitle sizeToFit];

  [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:lblTitle];
```

My Problem:
Sign Up and Sign In overlaps
[image]

Comment: The problem is you are adding a new subview every time, instead of replacing the original subview. Try setting the old subview to nil or reassigning the old subview with the new one.

Comment: @RPK How can I replace the old Subivew..Means How Can I get the reference of Old Subview in new Screen

Comment: When you push and pop view controllers in a UINavigationController, the view controllers may change but the navigation controller stays the same. You could try sub classing UINavigationController and keep a class reference to the nav bar sub view. You can then add the subview once in viewDidLoad and then just change it when needed.

Comment: @RPK how can i do this..Please asist me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1: each time you have to remove the custom UIView object added to the navigation bar

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews enumerateObjectsWithOptions:0 usingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    if ([obj isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

        [obj removeFromSuperview];

    }

}];

UILabel *lblTitle = [UILabel new];
lblTitle.text = text;
CGSize lblSize = [Utility sizeOfText:text withFont:kCGFontMedium(19)];
lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(60, 9, lblSize.width, lblSize.height);
lblTitle.font = kCGFontMedium(19);
lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[lblTitle sizeToFit];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:lblTitle];
```

Solution 2 : add the property in a class interface to store access to custom subview in the navigationBar

```
@property (weak, readwrite, nonatomic) UILabel *navSubView;

[self.lblTitle removeFromSuperview];
self.lblTitle = [UILabel new];
lblTitle.text = text;
CGSize lblSize = [Utility sizeOfText:text withFont:kCGFontMedium(19)];
lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(60, 9, lblSize.width, lblSize.height);
lblTitle.font = kCGFontMedium(19);
lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[lblTitle sizeToFit];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:lblTitle];
```

Comment: thanks it is working as expected..But I have one doubt..Suppose I have Six Screens then In all six screens will I have to write this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use the NavigationItem's "titleView" property

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:titleLabel.frame];[titleView addSubview:titleLabel];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;

This will ensure only one instance of title label exists, and it won't overlap the self.title either